# In Excel, is there a way to change columns so when I copy them, they are surrounded by double quotes and end with a comma

Tags: excel, string-concatenation

I have a dataset that looks something like this in excel

```
Name
Alex
Bill
Trevor
Patrick
Dennis
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to change the columns so they look like this:

```
Name
'Alex',
'Bill',
'Trevor',
'Patrick',
'Dennis',
```

Is this possible in excel. I have tried using the concatenate function but I can't use a single quote (non curly) in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
="'"&A2&"',"
```

[image]